# In which software do I add a watermark to the map?

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, title

I want to know in which software I can do the following operations (esri/ pci/ hexagon et.)?

1. Adding Watermark to the satellite image/coordinated map.
2. Make the added watermark invisible
3. Detect which user added the watermark. Is user detection possible?

example image :  https://sendgb.com/kZidJIqDjbH

We will be glad if you help.

Comment: What kind of images are we talking about? Which data type? Can you provide examples of your desired output?

Comment: I want to add watermark to Maps/satellite images like sentinel2 satellite image.  (example image: https://sendgb.com/kZidJIqDjbH  )

Comment: This might help you (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/creating-transparent-text-watermark-in-arcgis-for-desktop/126797#126797)

Comment: by definition a watermark is visible